# How to achieve user registration form in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part

Today I attend for an interview. There they asked one question like, I want to achieve user registration form for job portal. How we can achieve in sharepoint 2010? I said that create a webparts and deploy into site. But they said, that is wrong answer. We need simple and single piece solution which doesn't give any additional overhead. I said Site pages again, unfortunately that is also wrong answer. How to achieve this solution? Have any idea, which gives a very simple solution and no need to take any additional effort after deployed into the site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the definition of simple. Being a User Registration form you need to consider that user do NOT have accounts, therefore unless you open a full web to Anonymous the only feasible option would an Application Page that inherits from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase same way the Login Application pages do.

The registration form in itself is variable depending on requirements, so I wouldn't really count that!

This would also server other purposes - is available for any Site Collection, Web Application on the Farm.

Comment: @Marius... so you are saying the application pages are one of the solution, right!! But I said this answer to my interviewer, he said it is wrong. Infopath is not correct solution??

Comment: Site page (resides in either Site Pages/Pages libraries -requires user accounts) and Unsecured Application Page (resides in _layouts virtual folder) is not the same!

Comment: I cant understand your comment!

Comment: Is like Site pages - also could be Web Part pages, Wiki Pages, or Pages in the Publishing Library (stored in Content Databases too), whereas Application pages exist physically and are usually deployed by custom developments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution then you can go for infopath form which is very easy to develop and requires no additional overheads.

Comment: and infopath form can also reside inside infopath form webpart if they want it as a webpart.

Comment: @Alam... yes brother... at that time i didn't get idea. Thanks for this solution. Any better ideas more than this!!